# Read DWORD registry value in 64 bit

Tags: registry, wmi, wmi-query

How I can read `DWORD`registry value in 64 bit machine?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`StdRegProv.GetDWORDValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390445.aspx) method.

To specify whether to read this value from the 32-bit or 64-bit registry hive, you can use the `__ProviderArchitecture` flag, as explained in this article: [Requesting WMI Data on a 64-bit Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393067.aspx).